# React Native Adding array of Picker

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I wanted to add multiple pickers in React Native. I have a button when clicked a new picker should appear. I also want to store values of selected items of each picker in an array. I don't know how to make this possible. The callback of Picker onValueChange only sends item value and index in my case which can be same for 2 or more pickers. Please someone provide me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do something like this, in function handlePickerSelection you would be able to put value in array's element with index i

```
let pickers = [];
for ( let i = 0; i < numberOfPickers; i++) {
    pickers[i] = <Picker style={{height: 50, width: 100}} key={i} onValueChange={(value) => handlePickerSelection(value, i) }>
       <Picker.Item label="1" value={1}/>
       <Picker.Item label="2" value={2} />
   </Picker>
}
return (<View>{pickers}</View>)
```